# ASP.NET Web API 2 on Visual Studio for Mac 2017 RC

Tags: macos, asp.net-web-api2, webapi2, visual-studio-mac

I am new to Mac and was trying to build a Web API2 with Visual Studio 2017 for Mac. I am not able to see Web API 2 packages (Controller option is missing, I am able to create a MVC project but even when I select Empty Web Application -> Web API only)

I do not see API Controller and all Web API 2 options. Is there way to find and use these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While doing R&D I found that by default VS for Mac has your API project opened with Mono framework, when you go to Project -> Options (Properties) -> General ...you can change framework as .Net 4.x (upto 4.6.1) available as of now. Once done, you would be able to happily developer web API 2..

Posted here so it can be helpful for someone looking for same options :)